# Concurrent users at multi location using Firebird

Tags: firebird

How can I use firebird to connect to my database (host) from the other computer at different location 50km away?

Is there an online method? How to do it?

Comment: Can you explain bit more what are you trying to do, if you just want to connect to remote database only difference is in connection string.

Comment: Well 50km, better use post pingeons ))

Comment: Run Firebird as a server, and find a way to access that server (securely) remotely. Are you having problems with the first or the second part?

Answer (score 1):

I use SSH tunnels. On Ubuntu 14.04 with Upstart and autossh installed,

```
you@your-local-server:/etc/init$ cat autossh-other-server.conf
description "autossh other-server service"
version "1.0"
author "Your Name"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

script
        exec start-stop-daemon --start -c some-user-with-ssh-keys --exec /usr/bin/autossh -- -N -p 2022 other-server.your-domain.com -L 0.0.0.0:3052:localhost:3050
end script
```

Note that I already had a user setup with ssh keys for no-password ssh connections to the remote host. Your software on this side can connect to Firebird on port 3052.